# rotating row values in SQL

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of values that I want to rotate the values of.

For instance, suppose I have the given (sub) table:

```
id | value | other columns...
---+-------+---
 1 |  A    | ...
29 |  B    |
37 |  C    |
56 |  D    |
```

I want to rotate the values so that the final state of the table is:

```
id | value | other columns...
---+-------+---
 1 |  B    | ...
29 |  C    |
37 |  D    |
56 |  A    |
```

I know all the `id`s which should take part in the rotate.  However, I'm not sure how I would use this knowledge to update the values.  Something like this is not valid SQL:

```
UPDATE table SET value=('B','C','D','A') WHERE id IN (1,29,37,56)
```

Comment: Do you know all the new values (i.e., you do not need to read them from the DB)? How many can there be?

Comment: @CL. the new values are the same as the old values, only the actual row containing the values changes, they are just being shuffled around.  there is no hard limit on the number of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET value = CASE id
            WHEN  1 THEN 'B'
            WHEN 29 THEN 'C'
            WHEN 37 THEN 'D'
            WHEN 56 THEN 'A'
            END
WHERE id IN (1, 29, 37, 56);
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to do the rotation without needing to perform an extra query to get the values... so each literal value would need to be replaced by another select, e.g. `'B'` would be replaced by `(SELECT value FROM table WHERE id=1)`.   I was hoping for something a bit less wordy, but it works.

Comment: Hmm, except that fails due the selects not being atomic... (by the time we get to the last assignment, the new value is selected, not the old value)

Comment: Looks like I have to create a temporary table at the start, select the current value of (e.g.) id=1 into that table, then select out of the temporary table when 56.